# javascript: add element at end of parent element

Tags: javascript

I am integrating wordpress blog in my website. I am writing a script to add span tag at end of li element. The code is inserting all the span element at the last li element certification. I want each span to be added to each element of li element one by one in the nav menu.

The nav menu id is generated by wordpress dynamically. menu-item-84, menu-tem-85 and so on.

```js
  const text = ["Case Studies Intro", "Design Thinking Videos", "Graphic, Painting...", "UX, UI, Html, Css", "HFI, Adobe, Autodesk"];

  document.body.onload = addElement;  

  function addElement () {
  
    var arrayLength = text.length;
    var prefix = 'menu-item-'

for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)  {

    // create a new span element
    const newSpan = document.createElement("span");

 
        // and give it some content
    const newContent = document.createTextNode(text[i]);

  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newSpan.appendChild(newContent);

  for (let j = 83; j <= 87; j++) {

  let li1 = document.getElementById(prefix+j);

  li1.appendChild(newSpan);
}

}
  
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  
    <title>Casestudies, K.Deepak Madhana Raj</title>


  </head>
    
    
<body >

    <div class="container-fluid topheaderfill sticky-top">

    </div>



    
       <!-- nav bar-->

       <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-xl navbar-expand-xxl bg-light sticky-top ">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand logotext" href="index.html">kdeepakraj</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
              <h5 class="offcanvas-title font-weight600" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel"></h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
              <ul class="navbar-nav flex-sm-shrink-1 flex-md-shrink-1 flex-lg-fill font-30 text-center">
                
                <li id="menu-item-83" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html"><span class="active">Case Studies</span>
                  </a>

                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-84" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="uxprocess.html"><span>UX Process</span> 
                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-85" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="myhobbies.html"><span>My Hobbies</span> 
                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-86" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.kdeepakraj.com/blog/"><span>Blog</span> 
                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-87" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="certification.html"><span>Certification</span> 
                </li>

            </ul>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: That's because inside your loop over all the texts, you are looping over _all_ the LI from 83 to 87, instead of appending the span to just _one_ of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because you are creating a loop for the list item ids inside the loop used to create the text spans.

Instead, you can reference individual list items once for each value of `i`. This is simply achieved by summing the starting id number (83) with `i` to give 83, 84 ... 87 for values of i 0, 1 ... 4. Like this:

```
let li1 = document.getElementById(`menu-item-${83+i}`);
```

I've used a `template literal` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build the id but you could construct it with string catenation using the `+` operator.

This working snippet comments out the inner `j` loop and makes the above suggested modification.

```js
const text = ["Case Studies Intro", "Design Thinking Videos", "Graphic, Painting...", "UX, UI, Html, Css", "HFI, Adobe, Autodesk"];

  document.body.onload = addElement;  

  function addElement () {
  
    var arrayLength = text.length;
    var prefix = 'menu-item-'

for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)  {

    // create a new span element
    const newSpan = document.createElement("span");

 
        // and give it some content
    const newContent = document.createTextNode(text[i]);

  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newSpan.appendChild(newContent);

  // for (let j = 83; j <= 87; j++) {

  let li1 = document.getElementById(`menu-item-${83+i}`);

  li1.appendChild(newSpan);
//}

}
  
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  
    <title>Casestudies, K.Deepak Madhana Raj</title>


  </head>
    
    
<body >

    <div class="container-fluid topheaderfill sticky-top">

    </div>



    
       <!-- nav bar-->

       <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-xl navbar-expand-xxl bg-light sticky-top ">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand logotext" href="index.html">kdeepakraj</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
              <h5 class="offcanvas-title font-weight600" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel"></h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
              <ul class="navbar-nav flex-sm-shrink-1 flex-md-shrink-1 flex-lg-fill font-30 text-center">
                
                <li id="menu-item-83" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index.html"><span class="active">Case Studies</span>
                  </a>

                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-84" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="uxprocess.html"><span>UX Process</span> 
                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-85" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="myhobbies.html"><span>My Hobbies</span> 
                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-86" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.kdeepakraj.com/blog/"><span>Blog</span> 
                </li>

                <li id="menu-item-87" class="nav-item flex-lg-fill text-lg-center py-2">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="certification.html"><span>Certification</span> 
                </li>

            </ul>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      </body>
      </html>
```